# How to Mock OleDbDataAdapter(query, connStr)

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, moq, oledbdataadapter

How can i mock OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn) in FilledDataInDataTable function? Can i?
I have no idea how i do with dependency from query and connection string parameters.

```
Public Class DataTableOfDataFromExportCSV

   Private _adp As IOleDbDataAdapter

   Public Sub New(iadp As IOleDbDataAdapter)
       _adp = iadp
   End Sub

   Public Function FilledDataInDataTable(query As String, conStr As String) As DataTable

     Dim dt As New DataTable
     Dim adp = _adp.OleDbDataAdapter(query, conStr)
     adp.Fill(dt)

     Return dt

  End Function

End Class
```

Implementation

```
Public Class MyOleDbDataAdapter
 Implements IOleDbDataAdapter

 Public Function OleDbDataAdapter(query As String, conn As String) As OleDbDataAdapter Implements IOleDbDataAdapter.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn)
    Return adp

 End Function
End Class
```

My Interface

```
Public Interface IOleDbDataAdapter
   Function OleDbDataAdapter(query As String, conn As String) As OleDbDataAdapter
End Interface
```

Comment: Seems to me that the OleDbDataAdapter would work best as a tightly-coupled implementation detail of a slightly higher-level interface/object representing a more general data store.  Then, you wouldn't be mocking the OleDbDataAdapter, you'd be mocking your higher-level data store. YMMV, I haven't done much with abstracting over data storage.

Comment: Thank you @Craig :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I mock OleDbDataAdapter

You can't because it is `NotInheritable` (`sealed` - c#).

```
Public NotInheritable Class OleDbDataAdapter
Inherits DbDataAdapter
Implements ICloneable
```

What we have here is a [Leaky Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction).

Expose only what is explicitly needed to perform the desired function.

For example

```
Public Interface IOleDbDataAdapter
   Function Fill(query As String, dataTable As DataTable) As Integer
End Interface
```

That way, implementation details/concerns like `OleDbDataAdapter` wont cause tight coupling.

```
Public Class DataTableOfDataFromExportCSV

    Private adp As IOleDbDataAdapter

    Public Sub New(iadp As IOleDbDataAdapter)
        adp = iadp
    End Sub

    Public Function FilledDataInDataTable(query As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        adp.Fill(query, dt)
        Return dt
    End Function

End Class
```

Note the removal of runtime data that can be managed at the composition root when constructing your components' object graphs or after the component has already been constructed.

Comment: @PatZidane no worries, Glad to help. This is more of a design issue. The unit test only exposed the design issue at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nkosi, I am still new in Unit test and programming. I couldn't understand something from you're explain. I have to learn something more about your answer. Great!! Now I got it that I can not Mock OleDbDataAdapter. :)